# Select 0 values as existing column name

Tags: sql

Hi I have 2 tables with 3 columns:

**Locations**

`ID | KnownLocationID | Other
 1  | 2               | Test
 2  | 0               | TestOther`

**KnownLocations**

`ID | Title
 1  | KNOWNTest
 2  | KNOWNTestOther`

I need to pull all the Known Locations. If it's 0 I need to pull `Other`

So expected output of the first table should bring back:

`ID | Location
 1  | KNOWNTestOther
 2  | TestOther`

Expected output

Comment: Do an outer join, use coalesce to pick the non-null location value.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't tag which SQL are you asking about I assume it's MySQL. So you can simply use an `IF` function:

```
SELECT l.id, IF(l.KnownLocationID = 0, l.Other, kl.Title)
FROM Locations AS l
LEFT JOIN KnownLocations AS kl ON kl.ID = l.KnownLocationID
```

[Working Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c63a/1)

Comment: Use `case` or `coalesce` instead, and the query will work with most (all?) products.

Comment: Yes, I wasn't sure which one to use here, so I edited my comment. `case` is portable ANSI SQL, supported by MySQL as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it with `CASE`

```
SELECT l.id,
CASE WHEN l.KnownLocationID = 0 THEN l.other ELSE kl.Title END AS Location
FROM Locations AS l
LEFT JOIN KnownLocations AS kl ON kl.ID = l.KnownLocationID
```

Comment: [it's `CASE WHEN` not just `CASE`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bad2eb/20)

Answer (score 0):

**Query :**

```
SELECT loc.ID, IF(kl.Title IS NULL,loc.Other,kl.Title) AS Location FROM locations loc LEFT JOIN knownlocations kl ON kl.ID = loc. KnownLocationID
```